# GIT rebasing connected feature branches

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase, git-rebase, git-flow

I have a develop branch and one feature branch, let's call it feature/A.
When someone commites on remote develop, I am pulling it then I go to feature/A and rebasing it onto develop. Now I want to create new branch called feature/B and "inherit" it from feature/A and do some development (I need feature/A's code in feature/B), but I wonder what will happen when I will rebase my feature/A onto develop.

```
    dev
     |
1----4
 \
  \---2--------3
      |        |
     f/A      f/B
```

then I will commit on feature/A again

```
    dev
     |
1----4
 \
  \---2--------3
       \        |
        |      f/B
        5
       f/A
```

when I will rebase feature/A onto develop I will have

```
    dev      f/A
     |        |
1----4---2'---5'
 \
  \---2--------3
      /        |
     /        f/B
    5 (commit without any assiciated branch that git will remove as trash after several days)
```

Now I have to rebase feature/B onto feature/A right ? Is it possible that after that rebase commit 2 and 3 will override commit 2' and commit 5' and in my feature/B I will have old code again ?

Don't forget that I need commit 5 changes in my feature/B

Comment: I am worry that during rebase commit 2 will override commit 2' and I will have old codes. Can it happen ?

Comment: I need feature/A's code in featude/B but I can't merge feature/A with develop. in other words my feature/A always has dependency from feature/A

Comment: perform interactive rebase, and skip commit 2, or resolve a conflict in a way that does not override commit 2'

Comment: I have updated my question, please read it again

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I got what you said, and it looks like it really will solve the problem. thanks a lot. But is it the only method (except resolving conflicts manually) ?

Comment: You can also "cherry-pick" a single commit (commit 3 in this case)

Answer (score 1):

Well... `rebase` is a pretty flexible command.  It can do a lot of things, so the real question is how to tell it to do exactly what you mean.

So it seems the point of concern is when you have

```
1 -- 4 <--(dev)
 \    \
  \    2' -- 5' <--(A)
   \
    2 -- 3 <--(B)
```

how to rebase `B` onto `A`.  (The additional information you gave about how you got to this point doesn't really matter; we can just focus on the current commit graph.  The dangling commit `5` also doesn't really matter here.)

You ask about if `2` could end up overriding `2'` in some way... I don't see a concern there.  If the branch you're rebasing is `B`, `A` and its history will be unaffected.

A minor concern is that `2` is in the history of `B` but not the history of `A`.  This *shouldn't* be a problem, because we'd expect `2` to apply the same textual changes as `2'` - a condition rebase will detect.  But if there were conflict resolutions when rebasing `A` - or other, more obscure possibilities I suppose - the patch comparison might get messed up.

What that means is, you *should* be able to just say

```
git rebase A B
```

Commits `2` and `3` would be identified as the source commits, but `2` would hopefully be found as a duplicate of `2'` and discarded.  `3'` would be created to apply the changes from `3` (relative to `2`) on top of `5`, yielding

```
1 -- 4 <--(dev)
      \
       2' -- 5' <--(A)
              \
               3' <--(B)
```

If that fails then you'll probably see conflicts when git tries to replay `2`.  At that point you would abort the rebase.

(I can't see how this would happen, but if the rebase successfully completes and yet you find that it incorrectly re-copied changes from `2`, then you can still back it out; use

```
git checkout B
git reset --hard B@{1}
```

to undo the rebase.)

If you had to either abort the rebase or undo it, then "plan B" would be

```
git rebase --onto A 2 B
```

where `2` is an expression that refers to commit `2` (such as its SHA ID, or `B^` in the given example, etc.).  This will ensure that only `3` is considered as a candidate commit to rewrite (because `2` is the upstream) but will still perform the replay onto `5`.

Comment: don't know why this wasn't accepted - had a similar issue and this worked great